# Hijri datapicker missing autoclose

Tags: html, reactjs, datepicker

I'm using the following library for Arabic datepicker and it is missing the auto close function upon date selection. I tried many options but with no success. I appreciate some help over here.

## [Library](https://github.com/abublihi/datepicker-hijri)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0">
  <title>تجربة محدد التاريخ الهجري</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/abublihi/datepicker-hijri@master/build/datepicker-hijri.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tajawal&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Tajawal', serif;
    }
    .center {
      padding: 10% 0;
    }
    input {
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
</style>
<body style="text-align: center; height: 100hv;">
  <div class="center">
    <h2>تجربة محدد التاريخ الهجري</h2>
    <input type="text" id="calender" value="1441/02/01">
    <button id="calender2" onloadeddata="console.log(this)">حدد التاريخ :</button>
    <datepicker-hijri reference="calender" placement="bottom" selected-date="1441/02/01"></datepicker-hijri>
    <datepicker-hijri reference="calender2" placement="bottom" selected-date="1441/02/01"></datepicker-hijri>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the source code for the library](https://github.com/abublihi/datepicker-hijri/blob/d9004863483553026c9782fab239c51b825a5f6b/src/components/datepicker-hijri/datepicker-hijri.tsx) there is no option to automatically close the calendar popup after selecting a date.

You may want to raise a feature request over at GitHub issues for the project.

Comment: the calendar closes when clicking anywhere in the page. is there a way to mimic such action with jquery and bind it to input value change ? Thx